# How to avoid duplicate activities when resuming from home screen

Tags: android, android-activity, duplicates

i'm new to Android and java.
What i have is an activity that has a handler (h_main) and a runable (r_test).
* The runable is called in the activities onStart().
* The runable calls a function that gets me feedback via Log.d(TAG,"tick..").
* At the end of the function the runable get called again with delay of 1000ms.

That way i got my fuction called every second what works fine.
But when i return to Androids home screen and return to my app, i get
two 'ticks' per second.
It apears that my activity is running twice now. How can i avoid this?

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG,"onStart()");
    h_main.postDelayed(r_test, 1000);
}   

public void timer_runable() {
    Log.d(TAG,"tick..");
    h_main.postDelayed(r_test, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to cancle your pending runnable in `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    h_main.removeCallbacks(r_test);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that keep it running while the app is in background? I want to have a notification on certain conditions, they may appear while the app is not in foreground.

Comment: The normal way to achieve that would be to use a service.

Comment: So theres no fast/easy way for that? I hoped to concentrate first on the half-done funtionality before start to go into new topics.

Comment: Ok, i think i will go straight for the service. But for my understanding..could you explain what exactly is duplicated? The whole activity? Is there also the UI still alive? Why aint it just resumed if it's not killed by the system? Thanks a lot, Andreas

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here."  :/

Comment: I know I hoped that I could override that. You could use threads, but you would need to manage them yourself

Comment: Threads were my first approach. I checked if the thread exists in onStart before creating a new one. But i had the issue that the handler i used in my thread was still bound to the activity it was generated in. So i was unable to modifiy the new one.

Comment: If you manage them in your Application implementation, that class will exists in the whole life cycle of your app.

Comment: "no fast/easy way" no, you have to use service for stuff that will run after the activity is gone. "could you explain what exactly is duplicated?" Handler manages queue of events to be executed in a certain thread. The duplication is on this queue, the event is queue to be executed twice and it is. Google for the activity life-cycle, you'll see it goes through a lot of states, pressing `home` button goes to `stopped` (at first).